# calculating median over a column using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a sample table named Table1. In the table there are two columns ID and Age. I want to calculate median over age.
For this i have put on following SQL query

```
SELECT Age as Median FROM 
    (SELECT a1.Age, COUNT(a1.Age) Rank 
    FROM Table1 a1, Table1 a2 
    WHERE a1.Age < a2.Age OR a1.Age=a2.Age 
    group by a1.Age
    order by a1.Age desc) a3 
    WHERE Rank = (SELECT (COUNT(*)+1) DIV 2 FROM Table1);
```

But i am getting syntax error

```
syntax error in query expression Rank = (SELECT (COUNT(*)+1) DIV 2 FROM Table1)
```

Please tell where in i am missing

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: There are lots of examples of this sort of thing out there. Perhaps you're missing a search engine

Comment: Define median, please.

Comment: I am trying it in a simple msaccess database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think MS Access SQL has a `DIV` operator.

I think you need to workaround it using `/ 2` (divide by 2 resulting in a double float) or `* 0.5` (multiple by half, resulting in a fixed point decimal) then taking the integer part e.g. using `INT()`, noting it always rounds down so that `INT(0.9) == 0` and `INT(-0.1) == -1` but since the `COUNT` set function (cardinality) cannot return a negative value you should get the expected result e.g.

```
SELECT INT( ( COUNT(*) + 1 ) / 2 ) FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following query. It works fine now

```
SELECT Age as Median FROM 
    (SELECT a1.Age, COUNT(a1.Age) as Rank 
    FROM Table1 a1, Table1 a2 
    WHERE a1.Age < a2.Age OR a1.Age=a2.Age 
    group by a1.Age
    order by a1.Age desc) a3 
    WHERE Rank =(SELECT INT( ( COUNT(*) + 1 ) *0.5 ) FROM Table1);
```